# List from nested Values XML Linq C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am requesting some data from an API as XML. First to GET id's and then POST the id's to a second endpoint to get the data in question. 
The problem I'm having is to extract the id's and put them in a List like this one
`List<string>() { "idxxxx", "idxxxx", "idxxxx", "idxxxx" }` for the POST request body.
GET response (xmlStringResponse) looks like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><TaxeringsenhetsreferensResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:lmfault="http://namespace.lantmateriet.se/distribution/produkter/fault/v1" xmlns="http://namespace.lantmateriet.se/distribution/produkter/taxering/v2" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"><Taxeringsenhetsreferens><id>553508-5</id><typ>Lantbruksenhet</typ></Taxeringsenhetsreferens><Taxeringsenhetsreferens><id>553511-5</id><typ>Specialenhet</typ></Taxeringsenhetsreferens><Taxeringsenhetsreferens><id>559405-5</id><typ>Industrienhet</typ></Taxeringsenhetsreferens><Taxeringsenhetsreferens><id>710531-4</id><typ>Industrienhet</typ></Taxeringsenhetsreferens></TaxeringsenhetsreferensResponse>
```

The code looks like this at this time and the idListXml is keep being empty. I'm doing something wrong here and cant figure it out..

```
XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse(xmlStringResponse);

      var idList = xmlTree.Descendants("Taxeringsenhetsreferens")
                  .Select(x => (string)x.Element("id"))
                  .ToList();

      XElement requestBody = new XElement(ns + "IdRequest", idList.Select(l => new XElement(ns + "id", l)));
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your code works for me , I am getting values in `idList`

Comment: @Lucifer Thanks for replying. Hmm, what values are you getting back? I been testing different syntaxes but still recive idList Count = 0

Comment: can you check what are you sending in `xmlStringResponse`

Comment: Updated the question with the xmlStringResponse copied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is good, you can just add the **XNamespace**, try the following code :

```
XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse(xmlStringResponse);
XNamespace ns = "http://namespace.lantmateriet.se/distribution/produkter/taxering/v2";

var idList = xmlTree.Descendants(ns + "Taxeringsenhetsreferens")
            .Select(x => x.Element(ns + "id").Value)
            .ToList();
```

I hope this will help you get the expected result.